# Kaspersky Anti Virus software

Tags: macos

I'm trying to install Micro Trend Anti Virus; however, I at one time had Kaspersky Anti Virus software.  I can't download Micro Trend because it says Kaspersky needs to be removed.  However, I cannot find Kaspersky anywhere on my MAC in order to remove/uninstall.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how to remove this?

Answer (score 1):

You can download [Etrecheck](https://cdn.etrecheck.com/EtreCheckPro.zip) and the report can help you.
Then with the version of Kaspersky you can find an [uninstaller](https://support.kaspersky.com/kis20mac/install).